# Command Prompt not working to find IP address

Tags: windows, command-line

This was happened when i was trying to connect to internet in my friends home. He was using mac filter and somehow my laptop was unable to catch the ip address and default gateway automatically. I have decided to find it manually and typed ipconfig /all in command prompt. My command prompt was unable to execute and got stuck.

Question: How to find ipaddress and details when command prompt is not working and when we aren't connected to internet?
Also, why command prompt doesn't work?

Comment: Windows version may help

Comment: Perhaps it isn't releasing right and is in the acquiring stage indefinitely, can you do ipconfig --release and then ipconfig --renew try /all again?

Comment: ipconfig /all on your PC will only show you all the info your PC has - so if your PC isn't getting an IP / Gateway, then it just doesn't have it.  If you want to set an IP and gateway based on *his* Mac settings, have him type ifconfig -a in a terminal, and then use an IP address in the same subnet, and the same gateway on your PC.

Answer (score 3):

> **How to find ipaddress and details when command prompt is not working**

## 1) FIND

In Windows Vista (for example) Use Start -> ControlPanel -> View Network Status

[image]

## 2) SET

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused as to what you are asking.  If your friend is using MAC filtering, it is going to reject all connections from network cards that do not have a MAC address in the allowed list.  As for your IP address, your computer is most likely configured to use DHCP to obtain an IP address automatically and would only have a locally generated IP address if not connected to a network (which you can't connect to since your MAC isn't allowed to connect.)

If all you need is an IP address for some reason, you could setup a static IP address (or for that matter you can check your IP address) by going to your network configuration under Network, Network and Sharing Center, Change Adapter Settings and viewing the properties of the connection you are trying to use.

In your particular case though, it sounds like you need the MAC address instead.  From the Change Adapter Settings screen, double click your adapter and hit details.  The Physical Address is the MAC Address that needs to be added to the access control list on your friend's router.

Comment: See [Zero Configuration Networking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeroconf) - which is what often happens when your computer is not configured with a static addres sand can't get a response from DHCP.

Comment: Ah yes, forgot about that.  I'll edit my answer to reflect that.