# Wireless Router - Losing Connection, Very Low Speeds - Cause?? Test Results

Tags: wireless-networking, latency, speed, internet

Looking for answers to an ongoing problem with wireless internet through Time Warner (TWC). There have been 5 technicians out and they can't figure it out.

I found a link on [this forum](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/780/what-would-cause-high-latency-anytime-there-is-traffic-on-wan) suggesting running an MTR to test for latency issues. Here are the results (I've blacked out personal info):

[image: MTR Results]

I also ran Netalyzr and the results are [here](http://n1.netalyzr.icsi.berkeley.edu/restore/id=43ca253f-27167-f6db9b68-efaa-49ab-9e90/rd). (permalink)

Download speeds are supposed to/have been between 28-30 Mbps and uploads of 5 Mbps. Since the issue began 6 weeks ago (nothing changed as far as equipment, etc. in home), download is no higher than 15, but mostly between 1-4 Mbps, at best. The combined modem/router DOCSIS 3.0 (Motorola) is brand new, the modem settings have been reviewed, equipments (laptop, Android, iPad) all check out fine but all have wireless speed/streaming/connection issues. No one can figure out why.

Anything from the info above stand out to anyone?

Comment: Thanks, Mike. Will SuperUser send me email alerts if there are responses?

Comment: You [can subscribe to email updates here](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current).  The emails normally [can be sent within 3 hours of the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14555/notify-more-frequently-than-once-a-day/14600#14600), but you'll need to subscribe on [su] independent of this site.

Answer (score 0):

Your mtr shows about 2% packet loss to 8.8.8.8 over a 3 minute period.  This might indicate a problem and it might not.  Part of this depends on whether someone else in the house was consuming your internet bandwidth when you made the measurement.  I will try to outline a general framework for troubleshooting this below.

### Assumptions

When you say wireless, I am assuming it's wifi inside your house.  I'm assuming that wifi provides a connection to the cable modem (which you said is a DOCSIS 3.0 modem).

I am also assuming the topology looks something like this...

```
| <-------  Your Home Boundaries   ---> |

                  gw ip addr:
                  192.168.0.1
+------------+         +----------------+
|  Computer  |         |     Combined   |   DOCSIS 3.0 Internet from Time Warner
|  w/ wifi   | <wifi>  |     Wifi AP    |------->
|            |         | w/ Cable Modem |
+------------+         +----------------+
```

### Diagnosis

- Before you start, ensure that nobody else in the house is using the internet... perhaps the best thing you can do is turn off / disconnect all the other computers / phones / tablets in the house.
- If you haven't already done so, you need to separate your troubleshooting efforts into troubleshooting the wireless portion of your connection vs the wired portion of the connection.

  - Diagnose the Time Warner portion of the service first from a wired ethernet connection; you should expect a wired ethernet connection to have the least packet loss.

    - Normally, these modem / wifi units come with a wired ethernet jack on the back of them.  Use the wired ethernet port on a laptop and plug directly into the wired ethernet jack on the Time Warner modem.  You should automatically get an IP address from DHCP.
    - Perform an `mtr` directly to a site where you are having throughput problems.
    - `mtr` to 8.8.8.8
    - Compare these `mtr` runs and look for signs of trouble<sup>1</sup>.  If both are clean, then look at your wireless connection.  If they are not clean, you have something to show Time Warner<sup>2</sup> as long *as the packet drops happen inside their network*.
  - Diagnose the Wifi piece next.

    - If you're running windows, [use this sequence of clicks to find your IPv4 default gateway](https://superuser.com/a/493513/775) (look a few lines below his yellow highlighted piece)
    - Now run `mtr` to your default gateway.  In my text diagram of the house, I'm using 192.168.0.1, but it could be something else.
    - If you see sustained packet loss to the default gateway ip address, the problem is yours.
    - Wifi problems are tricky to fix.  You will need to ask a different question about fixing your wifi if it's really a problem.

---

**Footnotes**

<sup>**1**</sup> This is what a clean `mtr` could look like... normally I measure over a five minute period (or longer).  You can't expect TW to respond to short-term packet loss; they should fix on-going packet loss.  Keep in mind that "short-term" is somewhat subjective.

[image: mtr_example]

- Note points A, B, and C:

  - A & B show packet loss because the hops intentionally rate-limit traceroute responses.  In this case, it's not contributing to a problem getting to 4.2.2.2.
  - C does not show packet loss. Since it shows 0.0% loss, this is the only data point that matters.

Data points A & B might matter if the loss was constant or increasing at the same rate past one of the hops.

<sup>**2**</sup> For a cable modem connection, you really don't have grounds to complain unless there is sustained packet loss over 0.5% measured over *at least* a 5-minute period.  Remember you are sharing this cable with other people in your neighborhood.  Even 0.5% might not get much response from a cable ISP, but you will know about one contributing factor to your slower download speeds.